# Linked List Stack/Queue implementation emptying for no apparent reason?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue, empty-list

I've been trying to program a LinkedList implementation of a Stack and of a Queue.  Whenever I run them however, I get an error letting me know that the list is empty when I try and pop/dequeue anything.  The thing is, if I call .toString() on the list, even RIGHT before the pop/dequeue command, I can see that they're not.  I can't myself see anything wrong with my pop/dequeue implementation, but perhaps you fine folks can help me out.

## LinkedList.java

```
package jsjf;

import jsjf.exceptions.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * LinkedList represents a linked implementation of a list.
 * 
 * @author Java Foundations
 * @version 4.0
 */
public class LinkedList<T> implements ListADT<T>, Iterable<T>
{
    protected int count;
    protected LinearNode<T> head, tail;
    protected int modCount;

    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = tail = null;
        modCount = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new element to the end of the list.
     * 
     * @param element the element to add.
     */
    public void add(T element) {
        // If the list is empty...
        if(this.tail == null){
            // Creates a new node for the new element.
            LinearNode<T> newElement = new LinearNode(element);
            // Assigns the new node to be the head and the tail.
            this.tail = this.head = newElement;
        } 
        // Otherwise...
        else {
            // Temporary caches the old tail.
            LinearNode<T> temp = this.tail;
            // Creates a new node for the new element.
            LinearNode<T> newElement = new LinearNode(element);
            // Assigns the new node to follow the old tail.
            temp.setNext(newElement);
            // Assigns the old tail to precede the new node.
            newElement.setPrevious(temp);
            // Assigns the new node to be the tail.
            this.tail = newElement;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Adds a new element at a specific index, bumping the current element at 
     * that index to the next index.
     * 
     * @param index the index to add to.
     * @param element the element to add.
     */
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        // Find the node at the index requested.
        LinearNode<T> desiredIndex = this.head;
        for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++){
            desiredIndex = desiredIndex.getNext();
        }
        // Hold the previous element of the old element.
        LinearNode<T> prev = desiredIndex.getPrevious();
        // Create a new node for the new element.
        LinearNode<T> newElement = new LinearNode(element);
        // Assign prev to precede the new element.
        newElement.setPrevious(prev);
        // Assign the old element to follow the new element.
        newElement.setNext(desiredIndex);
        // Assign the new element to precede the old element.
        desiredIndex.setPrevious(newElement);
   }


    /**
     * Returns an element from a specific index, without removing it.
     * 
     * @param index the index to check.
     * @return the element at that index.
     */
    public T get(int index) {
        // Find the node at the index requested.
        LinearNode<T> desiredIndex = this.head;
        for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++){
            desiredIndex = desiredIndex.getNext();
        }
        // Return that element.
        return desiredIndex.getElement();
    }


    /** Removes the first element in this list and returns a reference
     * to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty.
     *
     * @return a reference to the first element of this list
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty
     */
    public T removeFirst() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");

        T result = head.getElement();
        head = head.getNext();
        count--;

        if(isEmpty())
            tail = null;

        modCount++;

        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Removes the last element in this list and returns a reference
     * to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty.
     *
     * @return the last element in this list
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty    
     */
    public T removeLast() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");

        T result = tail.getElement();
        tail = tail.getPrevious();
        count--;

        if(isEmpty())
            tail = null;

        modCount++;

        return result;
     }


    /**
     * Removes the first instance of the specified element from this
     * list and returns a reference to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException 
     * if the list is empty. Throws a ElementNotFoundException if the 
     * specified element is not found in the list.
     *
     * @param  targetElement the element to be removed from the list
     * @return a reference to the removed element
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty
     * @throws ElementNotFoundException if the target element is not found
     */
    public T remove(T targetElement) throws EmptyCollectionException, 
     ElementNotFoundException 
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("LinkedList");

        boolean found = false;
        LinearNode<T> previous = null;
        LinearNode<T> current = head;

        while (current != null && !found)
            if (targetElement.equals(current.getElement()))
                found = true;
            else
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }

        if (!found)
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("LinkedList");

        if (size() == 1)  // only one element in the list
            head = tail = null;
        else if (current.equals(head))  // target is at the head 
            head = current.getNext();
        else if (current.equals(tail))  // target is at the tail
        {
            tail = previous;
            tail.setNext(null);
        }
        else  // target is in the middle
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());

        count--;
        modCount++;

        return current.getElement();
    }


    /**
     * Changes the element at a specific index.
     * 
     * @param index the index to change.
     * @param element the element to change to.
     */
    public void set(int index, T element) {
        // Find the node at the index requested.
        LinearNode<T> desiredIndex = this.head;
        for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++){
            desiredIndex = desiredIndex.getNext();
        }
        // Change the element at that index.
        desiredIndex.setElement(element);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the first element in this list without removing it. 
     *
     * @return the first element in this list
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty
     */
    public T first() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");

        T result = head.getElement();
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the last element in this list without removing it. 
     *
     * @return the last element in this list  
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty
     */
    public T last() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");

        T result = tail.getElement();
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the specified element is found in this list and 
     * false otherwise. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the list 
     * is empty.
     *
     * @param  targetElement the element that is sought in the list
     * @return true if the element is found in this list
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the list is empty
     */
    public boolean contains(T targetElement) throws 
         EmptyCollectionException 
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");

        boolean found = false;
        LinearNode<T> previous = null;
        LinearNode<T> current = head;

        while (current != null && !found)
            if (targetElement.equals(current.getElement()))
                found = true;
            else
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }

        if (!found)
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("LinkedList");

        return found;
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if this list is empty and false otherwise.
     *
     * @return true if the list is empty, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (count == 0);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this list.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in the list
     */
    public int size()
    {
        return count;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this list.
     *
     * @return a string representation of the list    
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        LinearNode current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            result = result + current.getElement() + "\n";
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        return result;
    }


    /**
     * Returns an iterator for the elements in this list. 
     *
     * @return an iterator over the elements of the list
     */
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }


    /**
     * LinkedIterator represents an iterator for a linked list of linear nodes.
     */
    private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T>
    {
        private int iteratorModCount;  // the number of elements in the collection
        private LinearNode<T> current;  // the current position

        /**
         * Sets up this iterator using the specified items.
         *
         * @param collection  the collection the iterator will move over
         * @param size        the integer size of the collection
         */
        public LinkedListIterator()
        {
            current = head;
            iteratorModCount = modCount;
        }

        /**
         * Returns true if this iterator has at least one more element
         * to deliver in the iteration.
         *
         * @return  true if this iterator has at least one more element to deliver
         *          in the iteration
         * @throws  ConcurrentModificationException if the collection has changed
         *          while the iterator is in use
         */
        public boolean hasNext() throws ConcurrentModificationException
        {
            if (iteratorModCount != modCount) 
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

            return (current != null);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the next element in the iteration. If there are no
         * more elements in this iteration, a NoSuchElementException is
         * thrown.
         *
         * @return the next element in the iteration
         * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iterator is empty
         */
        public T next() throws ConcurrentModificationException
        {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();

            T result = current.getElement();
            current = current.getNext();
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * The remove operation is not supported.
         * 
         * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the remove operation is called
         */
        public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

}
```

## LinkedListQueue.java

```
package jsjf;

public class LinkedListQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T> {

    LinkedList queue = new LinkedList();


    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the back of this queue.
     * 
     * @param element generic element to be pushed onto queue.
     */
    public void enqueue(T element) {
        queue.add(element);
    }


    /**
     * Removes the element from the front of the queue and returns it.
     * 
     * @return the element from the front of the queue.
     */
    public T dequeue() {
        return (T) queue.removeFirst();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the front element, without removing it.
     * 
     * @return the element at the front of the queue.
     */
    public T first() {
        return (T) queue.first();
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the queue is empty.
     * 
     * @return the boolean value of this queue being empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(queue.isEmpty())
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number of elements contained in the queue.
     * 
     * @return the number of elements contained in the queue.
     */
    public int size() {
        return queue.size();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the queue as a string.
     * 
     * @return the queue as a string.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return queue.toString();
    }
}
```

## LinkedListStack.java

```
package jsjf;

public class LinkedListStack<T> implements StackADT<T> {

    LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();


    /**
     * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.
     * 
     * @param element generic element to be pushed onto stack.
     */
    public void push(T element) {
        stack.add(element);
    }


    /**
     * Removes the element from the top of the stack and returns it.
     * 
     * @return the element from the top of the stack.
     */
    public T pop() {
        return (T) stack.removeLast();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the top element, without removing it.
     * 
     * @return the element at the top of the stack.
     */
    public T peek() {
        return (T) stack.last();
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if the stack is empty.
     * 
     * @return the boolean value of this stack being empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(stack.isEmpty())
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number of elements contained in the stack.
     * 
     * @return the number of elements contained in the stack.
     */
    public int size() {
        return stack.size();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the stack as a string.
     * 
     * @return the stack as a string.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return stack.toString();
    }

}
```

## Driver.java

```
package jsjf;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Instantiate the array based structures.
        ArrayListQueue arrayQueue = new ArrayListQueue();
        ArrayListStack arrayStack = new ArrayListStack();

        // Instantiate the link based structures.
        LinkedListQueue linkedQueue = new LinkedListQueue();
        LinkedListStack linkedStack = new LinkedListStack();

        // An integer to hold reference to a data piece to be pushed to the structures.
        int data;

        // Randomly generate a piece of data, and pass it to the structures.
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            data = (int)(Math.random() * 50);
            arrayQueue.enqueue(data);
            arrayStack.push(data);
            linkedQueue.enqueue(data);
            linkedStack.push(data);
        }


        System.out.print("Array Queue: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            System.out.print(arrayQueue.dequeue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print("Array Stack: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            System.out.print(arrayStack.pop() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("\n\nLinked Stack as string: " + linkedStack.toString() + "\n\n");


        System.out.print("Linked Stack: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            System.out.print(linkedStack.pop() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();


        System.out.print("Linked Queue: " + linkedQueue.toString());


        System.out.print("Linked Queue: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            System.out.print(linkedQueue.dequeue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();


    }

}
```

When I run Driver.java, I get the following output.

```
Array Queue: 45 12 25 40 31 32 14 16 14 26 3 25 22 26 29 6 13 12 30 10 46 10 11 3 11 
Array Stack: 11 3 11 10 46 10 30 12 13 6 29 26 22 25 3 26 14 16 14 32 31 40 25 12 45


Linked Stack as string: 45
12
25
40
31
32
14
16
14
26
3
25
22
26
29
6
13
12
30
10
46
10
11
3
11


Linked Stack: Exception in thread "main" jsjf.exceptions.EmptyCollectionException: The list is empty.
    at jsjf.LinkedList.removeLast(LinkedList.java:135)
    at jsjf.LinkedListStack.pop(LinkedListStack.java:24)
    at jsjf.Driver.main(Driver.java:46)
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use the debugger and step through the code one line at a time. Have you done that yet?

Comment: Please show **Minimal** , Complete, and Verifiable example. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't increment count in your add methods for the linked list, but are using count to determine if its empty or not.